# Testing classes with inheritance under JUnit suite

Tags: java, junit

There is a test class, for example, X marked with `@RunWith(TestSuite.class)` and another test class, say, Y which extends X.

1) Would test class Y be executed under same Suite i.e. `TestSuite.class`?

2) Is above true for all test classes which extend test class X?